# How to convert a string to the type of "double quotes"

Tags: php

Сreated client-side template

```
<textarea name="template">text {$text} text</textarea>

<?
    $template = $_REQUEST['template'];
    $text = 'working!';
    echo $template; // but displays 'text {$text} text', instead of 'text working! text'
?>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in your textarea, $text is not a variable, but a string, hence you have to replace it with str_replace or preg_replace.

try this:

```
<?
$template = $_REQUEST['template'];
$text = 'working!';
$replaced = str_replace('{$text}', $text, $template);
echo $replaced;
?>
```